# Advance gradient effect button CSS3

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm learning about gradient effects in css, then i found this buuton, i searched a lot to find any solution on internet to create same button effect. is that possible to create it in css?[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrbz0.png)

Comment: You can use background-image as an alternative.

Comment: yes i can use it. but i'm learning about gradient effects, that's why i have asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually possible, but not with css gradient only.

You have to use an SVG for the curve, hover a gradient to have this effect.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FAB14C;
  
  /* Two background image: a SVG curve hover a linear-gradient */
  background-image: 
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0,80 C50,100 50,0 100,20 L100,100 L0,100" fill="%23FAB14C"></path></svg>'),
    linear-gradient(to top, #FAB14C, white);
  
  /* The backgrounds are stretch to the element size */
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button">
  Edit this article
</button>
```

Comment: Its just perfect. Thanks

Comment: For fun, I also added an hover effect => https://jsfiddle.net/tzi/z1dj5bzL/